# DrawLayout within RecycleView

Tags: android

I want to use DrawLayout within RecycleView as a sliding menu.
But here is a question.
I close drawer in onBindViewHolder method if reuse View, the drawer does dismiss, but views within drawer still exsist.
Maybe describe not clear, check my screenshot below:

**Here is the Recycleview, and I got a ic_launcher imageView with the drawer:**
[screenshot0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BScjl.png)

**ITEM LAYOUT**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/dl"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And I scroll the recycleView,this happens:
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoNK8.png)

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RVDLViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder.dl.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.END)) {
        holder.dl.closeDrawer(Gravity.END, false);
    }
}
```

the drawer(cl_menu) is dismiss, but views within the drawer(ic_launcher) still exsist.I don't know where the error is,any have any ideas?Thanks!

Comment: Inflate the drawlayout as the view of the recyclerview

Comment: @LunarWatcher it works! thank you!